# Select nth-of-type even on gallery items

Tags: css, css-selectors

Im having some troubles finding the right way to create a selector on my webpage.
Basically, im building an **image gallery, with two types of images**, those with small width (50% of total wrapper width) and those with large width (100% of total wrapper width).

Im **trying to select the even small** width images to apply a margin on the left on them, but Im having troubles when there is a mix between small and large images.
When there is a large image between the small ones, my nth-of-type(2n) selector breaks, and doesn´t select properly.

I wrote a simple Codepen to test it, and I dont seem to be able to make it work properly.

```
[https://codepen.io/Gekyzo/pen/zZgEYL]
```

**My goal is to select the right positioned small** so I can apply a left-border on them.

Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:nth-of-type` matches the **type** and not the class. Which means you have to add classes to the even ones manually or using Javascript or jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".small:odd").addClass('green');
});
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmVGGw)

Comment: Thanks, that fix the problem.